# Comparing Multi and single dimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to php just playing with some array. 
I Want to get following things from the array which are of different dimensional

The following is the Multidimensional Array

```
$a = array(
array(
    'productsid' => 90,
    'CouponID' => 50
),
array(
    'productsid' => 80,
    'CouponID' => 95
),
  array(
    'productsid' => 80,
    'CouponID' => 95
));
```

The following is Single dimensional array:

```
$b = array(80,90,95);
```

I want to compare only the productsid index of the array with the single dimensional array and wants to fetch the data which is equal to it.

I Have tried the following loop to print but it only gives the values of the productsid only but I want that full array. But only by comparing the Productid with the second array.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
foreach ($a[$i] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($b as $c) {
        if ($value == $c) {
            echo $value .'<br>';

        }
    }
} }
```

Comment: Try using [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) in the inner loop.

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$result = array();
foreach($a as $item)
    if(in_array($item['productsid'], $b))
        $result []= $item;
```

or, in a more concise (but less readable IMO) way:

```
$result = array_filter($a, function($item) use($b) {
    return in_array($item['productsid'], $b);
});
```

For your test data it's doesn't matter much, but if your arrays are big and/or this loop is going to run many times, you can achieve better performance by converting the lookup array into a hash table and using `O(1)` key lookup instead of linear array search:

```
$bs = array_flip($b);
$result = array_filter($a, function($item) use($bs) {
    return isset($bs[$item['productsid']]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$b = array(80,90,95);
$c = array();
foreach($a as $val) {
    if(in_array($val['productsid'],$b)) {
        $c[] = $val;    
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($a as $ar) {
    if (in_array($ar['productsid'], $b))
        print_r($ar);
}
```