# How can match two array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array:

**One Array**

`$workingDays = ['2019-11-01','2019-11-02','2019-11-03','2019-11-04'];`

**Other Array**

```
$doneWork = array(
     array(
       'id' => 1,
       'date' => '2019-11-01',
       'work' => 'done' 
     ),
    array(
       'id' => 1,
       'date' => '2019-11-02',
       'work' => 'done' 
     ),
    array(
       'id' => 1,
       'date' => '2019-11-04',
       'work' => 'done' 
     )
);
```

My Question: How can check which date not exist in **$doneWork** array

Comment: Have you looked at [Comparing Multi and single dimensional arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865677/comparing-multi-and-single-dimensional-arrays-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd start by extracting the dates from $doneWork using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php).

```
   $doneWork = [
        [
            'id'   => 1,
            'date' => '2019-11-01',
            'work' => 'done',
        ],
        [
            'id'   => 1,
            'date' => '2019-11-02',
            'work' => 'done',
        ],
        [
            'id'   => 1,
            'date' => '2019-11-04',
            'work' => 'done',
        ],
    ];
    $doneWorkDays = array_map(function ($element) {
        return $element['date'];
    }, $doneWork);

    print_r($doneWorkDays);
```

Will print:

```
  Array ( [0] => 2019-11-01 [1] => 2019-11-02 [2] => 2019-11-04 )
```

Then check which elements in `$workingDays` are not in such array, using [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php)

```
   $diff = array_diff($workingDays, $doneWorkDays);
   print_r($diff);
```

Will print:

```
    Array ( [2] => 2019-11-03 )
```

Pay attention, the result gives you not only the elements but also their index in the original array. If you don't care about these, use instead:

```
  print_r(array_values($diff));
```

Why would anyone need such index? Well, perhaps you could need to report not only how many days were missed but also check if two missing elements are adjacent.

(the indexes are relevant only for the array you're comparing against. It doesn't matter in what position they appear in `$doneWork`  )

**Edit:**

You say you need the results to be in "doneWork" format, which is an associative array with `id` (always zero), date and work (always 'absent').

Let's say your workin days are now

```
  $workingDays = [
      '2019-11-01', 
      '2019-11-02', 
      '2019-11-03', 
      '2019-11-04', 
      '2019-11-05'
  ];
```

So there are two missing days. Again, array map to the rescue:

```
   // from previous answer
   $diff = (array_diff($workingDays, $doneWorkDays));


   // map each missing date to a doneWork array
   $diff_assoc = array_values(
       array_map(function($date) {
         return  [ 
           'id' => 0,
           'date' => $date,
           'work' => 'absent'
         ];
       },$diff)
   );
```

That will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [date] => 2019-11-03
            [work] => absent
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [date] => 2019-11-05
            [work] => absent
        )

)
```

Again, note I'm wrapping the result in `array_values` because you need a plain array as result instead of:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [date] => 2019-11-03
            [work] => absent
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [date] => 2019-11-05
            [work] => absent
        )

)
```

Comment: @amenadeil your code working fine.  but i need which date not match  this date return ` [
            'id'   => 0,
            'date' => 'this date',
            'work' => 'absent',
        ],` like that

Answer (score 0):

```
$nonExistingDates = [];
$doneWorkDays = [];
foreach($doneWork as $work) {
    $doneWorkDays[] = $work['date'];
}

$nonExistingDates = array_diff($workingDays, $doneWorkDays);

// optional, removes duplicate dates
$nonExistingDates = array_unique($nonExistingDates);
```

Comment: return only empty array

Comment: My bad, I misread the question. I updated my answer, although @amenadiel's answer is better.

Comment: i know @Arsi. but need some more i comment it